# Best practices for structuring Python project with non python files e.g. DLL, .c, .cpp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, structure, project, project-structure

I'm wondering where shall I put my **non-python** files (**DLL, .c, .cpp**). Currently I keep it in '**resources**' folder under my package destination:

```
my_project/
   docs\
   my_pkg/
       resources/
         API.dll
       __init__.py
       module.py
   tests\
       test_module
   .gitignore
   README.md
   MANIFEST.in
   requirements.txt
   setup.py
```

I want to know what is Pythonic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect place, see [Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/). Don't forget to put the files into *setup.py* or *MANIFEST.in*.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think `graft my_pkg` in **MANIFEST.in** and `include_package_data=True` in **setup.py** is enough?

Comment: `graft my_pkg/resources`